# Show UTC Time in Google Chrome in Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, timezone, kendo-grid

I am working on Kendo Grid and want time in UTC in Google Chrome, It is Okay in Firefox.
I did like Below.

```
kendo.toString(new Date(date).toUTCString(), "g");
```

But It is not working.
Please find my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvh0hq6m/1/)

Please help on this.

Answer (score -1):

Try the 'u' specifier in kendo.

```
kendo.toString(new Date(date), "u");
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateformatting

Update: Placed code sample